# RSA Encryption Between C and C#

Tags: c#, c, openssl, rsa

I am trying to write a simple RSA encryption scheme to encrypt a small message between a single server and potentially many clients.

The plan I have come up with is to have the client generate a key pair and send the public key to the server. The server has an object that will store the socket and the public key. When it comes time to send the message the server will call a method in the Client object that will encrypt the message and send it down to the client.

I will only be encrypting the messages going to the client, so I don't need to worry about a full transaction of keys.

I think I have that pretty well figured out.

The problems are coming from trying to connect two different implementations of RSA. The server is written in C# and the client is a MetaTrader client using C. I have decided to use OpenSSL to try to bridge the gap, but so far I haven't been able to produce a key on the client. I am using the openssl wrapper for c# (http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/) and I am trying to write a very basic wrapper dll for MetaTrader. So far it contains two functions, GenerateRSAKeys and DecryptRSA.

For now, I would just like to produce a PEM formatted string that contains the public key. This is what I have so far for GenerateRSAKeys().

```
extern "C" unsigned char *__stdcall GenerateRSAKeys (){

int len;
unsigned char *buf = new unsigned char[1024];

rsa = RSA_generate_key(512,RSA_F4,NULL,NULL);

len=i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsa, &buf);

return buf;}
```

Right now, when sending buf to the server I receive a single character. Such as, "X"

So my first question is, what is the best way to export the generated public key?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ] and [ASK] carefully before asking a question..

Comment: Whoops. I didn't realize that was considered a signature.

Comment: `i2d` is shorthand for "internal to DER". If you want PEM output you'll have to use different methods. Also, your method is returning a pointer to 1024 bytes, not characters. It makes no sense to "print" it out as a string. Try using [`PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(...)`](http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html#) with a [memory BIO](http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html#). Good luck at trying to read that awful documentation.

Comment: That makes sense that it is returning an address instead of the actual characters. As for DER vs PEM, I really don't mind either. I just need to figure out how to get the public key into a portable format that I can send over a socket. A string would make it much easier. I'll start looking into the BIO's. I have tried to read up on them before, but as you pointed out, the documentation leaves some to be desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a buffer allocated on the stack; this buffer will be overwritten when the function returns.  Try `buf = new unsigned char[1024];`

Comment: As you can probably tell, C is not my first language. The original post has been updated to the current state of the code. It is now returning a single character "X".

Comment: I think he should change that little `new` over there to a `malloc` call; he tagged the question as a C and not C++.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @adel. I changed the line to `unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char *)malloc(1024);` But it was no different from the original. It returned a single "X".

Comment: How are you testing to know if it returned "X"? are you actually printing the results?

Comment: I am printing the result of GenerateRSAKeys();

Comment: You gotta be careful when printing out binary data, you might come along a NULL value before the buf is fully printed and that will cause printf to stop printing any more characters.
Please run your program in a debugger and let us know what exactly is the value of buf before it's returned

Comment: This was a problem along with dependency issues with my dll. Rebuilding everything from source and statically linking them solved my problems.